# Automatically parse DateTime object to formatted date string in doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

Suppose i fetch some array-object (fetch entity via `getArrayResult()`) and it contains `DateTime` field. If i dump this field:

```
"createdAt": {
    "date": "2016-06-13 19:35:28.000000",
    "timezone_type": 100500,
    "timezone": "Some/Timezone"
}
```

i see that i have not normal (nice formatted) date string, but `DateTime` object. Of course, i can write something like this to get nice format string:

```
$result['createdAt'] = $result['createdAt']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

but if i need to fetch, for example, 10.000 items (not sure that this happened :) ) and then do `for` loop to update each `createdAt` field... I think it's at least ugly solution, so maybe there are some nice solutions or best practices for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your createdAt field would be not set. It should be nullable=false / NOT NULL in your database so that you don't have to check. This would be best practice.

I mean, it was created at some point, but it has no created at? That makes no sense :)

Comment: sure, nice comment. but it not the answer to my question. P.S. update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the array to JSON using [Symfony Serializer components](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) and format the DateTime object using DateTimeNormalizer.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new DateTimeNormalizer('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$jsonResult = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json');
```